# font for charset GB2312.1980-0 is lacking when launching xorg in freebsd

Tags: freebsd

I am a newbie of freebsd (FreeBSD 12.0). I got a warning when launching xorg:

twm: warning: font for charset GB2312.1980-0 is lacking

How can I install the font? I googled it but can't find a solution.

Thanks.